# Why isn't this simple insert statement working (PDO)?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The code is simple- take a value from a form, insert it into the mysql DB.  Here's a snippet:

```
//connect to DB
$dbh = new PDO($db_pdo, $db_user_name, $db_password);

//capture value from form
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];

//insert value into DB (doesn't work- no new entry created in requests)
$dbh->exec("INSERT INTO requests(first_name) VALUES($first_name)");

//this echo statement works (outputs the value of $first_name):
echo "\$first_name ".$first_name;

//this insert statement works: 
$dbh->exec("INSERT INTO requests(first_name) VALUES('oleg')");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's right, you have to quote your string.

```
$dbh->exec("INSERT INTO requests(first_name) VALUES('$first_name')");
```

But this code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. I'm not sure how do you protect against that in PHP.

Comment: I'm not a fan of relying on PHP to figure out that a variable is in text... I'd at least try `$dbh->exec("INSERT INTO requests(first_name) VALUES('{$first_name}')");`

Comment: It's worth saying that there are prepared statements PDO available

Comment: @JoshToth: modern IDEs highlight such splices, not a problem. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev: nah, too boring to describe it for the zillionth time )

Comment: Thanks.  I realize that it is vulnerable to a whole range of issues- my next step is security- just wanted to get the basic db working.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: No, you're right - I'm just stuck in olden days on occasion haha

Comment: @Olegious `$first_name = htmlentities($first_name,ENT_QUOTES);` will save you from injection....or similar techniques